# Resolving a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" in Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Sorry if this seems like a really basic question, the concept of cloud functions is extremely new to me and i'm still highly in the learning process.

However, whilst trying to execute this cloud function i get the following error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Full log can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBPxT.jpg)

For reference as well, I didnt make this function, im just trying to get it working, i used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGBIb5H2_Xg) video.

The actual cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const firestore = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampInSnapshots: true };
firestore.settings(settings);

const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.token);

exports.addStripeSource = 
functions.firestore.document('cards/{userid}/tokens/{tokenid}')
.onCreate(async (tokenSnap, context) => {

    var customer;
    const data = tokenSnap.after.data();

    if (data === null) {
        return null
    }
    const token = data.tokenId;
    const snapchat = await 
    firestore.collection('cards').doc(context.params.userId).get();
    const customerId = snapshot.data().custId;
    const customerEmail = snpashot.data().email;

    if (customerId === 'new') {
        customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            email: customerEmail,
            source: token
        });

firestore.collection('cards').doc(context.params.userId).update({
            custId: customer.id
        });
    }

    else {
        customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId)
    }

    const customerSource = customer.sources.data[0];

    return firestore.collection('cards').doc(context.params.userId).collection('sources').doc(customerSource.card.fingerprint).set(customersource, { merge: true });})
```

The dart code im using for writing a payment service:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class PaymentService {
  addCard(token) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user) {
      print("Found User");
      Firestore.instance
          .collection('cards')
          .document(user.uid)
          .collection('tokens')
          .add({'tokenId': token}).then((val) {
        print('saved');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

And finally, what executes when i push the button:

```
StripeSource.addSource().then((String token) {
            print("Stripe!");
            PaymentService().addCard(token);
          });
```

As you can see the code is clearly being triggered, but i guess there is some sort of error with the data var, JavaScript is brand new to me so im sure its some sort of very dumb syntax issue.

Comment: In this line of code ".onCreate(async (tokenSnap, conetxt) => {" spelling of context is wrong

Comment: Apologies @randomSoul, I somehow missed that, i managed to Mis spell my code in-between asking my actual question and posting on StackOverflow. How embarrassing! Sorry about that! Updated the log and my code.

Comment: It seems like data is a property but in your code `const data = tokenSnap.after.data();` it is specified as a function. Try changing it to `tokenSnap.after.data`. Check what are you getting in 'tokenSnap' variable by doing `console.log(tokenSnap)`.

Comment: @randomSoul [Logs](https://imgur.com/a/6Rlx7Mb) with your edits included to the code

            `console.log(tokenSnap);`

    `const data = tokenSnap.after.data;`

Comment: The logs which you have provided are different. Your data variable is not getting anything, it is undefined. Try changing `if (data === null) {return null}`  to `if(!data) return null`;

Comment: @JacobPyke did you have any luck with this...I'm following the same tutorial!

Comment: I use the same code but it's not working now. I copy your code but the same error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log image attached the error is `context is not defined`

```
functions.firestore.document('cards/{userid}/tokens/{tokenid}')
.onCreate(async (tokenSnap, conetxt) => {
```

In the above function, you have passed parameter as `conetxt` and later in the function `context` is used, because of which it is giving `undefined` error.

Change the parameter name `conetxt` to `context`.

Answer (score 0):

As your provided log output explains : you need to define a reference for your firestore.document function :

```
functions.firestore.document('cards/{userid}/tokens/{tokenid}')
```

modify it to :

```
functions.firestore.documentReference(){


}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code because of a Spelling error regarding the `context` parameter, is this answer still valid with my updates?

Comment: Yes it was, i have since altered it